# Cake PHP adding and editing a record

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.x

So I am new to cake PHP. I am trying to have my database structured so a user can add an activity to a venue but if the venue already has that particular activity it doesn't add the record. For example;

Rose and crown = Pin-Pong
Rose and Crown = snooker 
Rose and Crown = table tennis

At the moment a you can have the same venue multiple times even with the same activity.For example;

Rose and crown = Pin-Pong
Rose and Crown = snooker 
Rose and Crown = table tennis
Rose and crown = Pin-Pong

```
public function add()
{
    $venueActivity = $this->VenueActivities->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $venueActivity = $this->VenueActivities->patchEntity($venueActivity, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->VenueActivities->save($venueActivity)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The venue activity has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The venue activity could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $venues = $this->VenueActivities->Venues->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $activities = $this->VenueActivities->Activities->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('venues', 'venueActivity', 'activities'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['venueActivities']);
}
```

I have been able to work out how to overwrite the record completely so their is only ever one record for venue (see code below) but I need it to only overwrite the record if the same activity has been inputted. But you can have the having all the different activities.

```
public function add()
{

    $venueActivity = $this->VenueActivities->newEntity();
    if($this->request->is('post')) {

        $venueActivity = $this->VenueActivities->patchEntity($venueActivity, $this->request->data);

        $oldVenueActivity = $this->VenueActivities->find()->where(['venue_id' => $venueActivity->venue_id]);

        foreach($oldVenueActivity as $activity) {
            $this->VenueActivities->delete($activity);
        } 

        if ($this->VenueActivities->save($venueActivity)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The venue activity has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The venue activity could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

    $venues = $this->VenueActivities->Venues->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $activities = $this->VenueActivities->Activities->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('venues', 'venueActivity', 'activities'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['venueActivities']);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider rethinking your approach for this particular problem.

What you have right now: venues, activities, and venue_activities. You are operating on VenueActivities, to join venue and activity together.

What (in my opinion) you should do: bake only Venues and Activities, and setup for them belongsToMany association in their Table classes. Then, in VenueController, you can create, for example, manageActivities function:

```
public function manageActivities($id = null){
    $venue = $this->Venues->get($id);
    if($this->request->is(['post','put'])){
        //patch entity and save
    }
    $activities = $this->Venues->Activities->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('venue','activities');
}
```

Then, in manage_activities.ctp:

```
$this->Form->input('activities._ids', ['multiple' => 'checkbox']);
```

Code above will result in multi-selectable list of Activities. If you will check additional activity, association with it will be added. If you will uncheck existing one, association with this particular Activity will be removed, and rest of selected ones will be preserved.

Additional info: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations